# Finding JARS on the web for a class

Tags: java, jar, oracle-ucm

I'm working on trying to find a jar(s) file for the following imports. This is pertaining to a custom component for Oracle's UCM (Universal Content Manager). Two websites that come up no longer exist (findjar.com). I've been searching for possible code examples that would include the jars, but at this point, I have not found a solution. I've searched for websites that would aid me in finding the jar file that contains the class/path below. Is there another website that replaces findjar.com?

```
import intradoc.shared.*;
import intradoc.common.*;
import intradoc.data.*;
import intradoc.server.*;
import intradoc.resource.*
```

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: Anyway, I'm afraid Oracle's UCM-related jars are only available through Oracle products, so I guess the only legal way to get them is through Oracle.

Comment: The response we've been getting is they don't support custom components when we ask where the packages/jars are available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This file is available on the UCM server. You can locate it like this:

- Log in as an administrator
- Go to Administration / Configuration for ...
- Expand class path details. There you will find something ending with `wccontent/ucm/idc/jlib/idcserver.jar`. That is the path on the server. Download that file and you have everything you need.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! That helped me find the needed jar files. My team was pushed into the deep end to see if we can swim on this upgrade project. Now we have gain quite a bit with this little bit of information.